# How to draw a transparent circle?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm trying to draw a transparent circle, but it just doesn't work.

when I'm drawing a bitmap it works, but a circle doesn't become transparent.

Here's my code in short:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAlpha(125);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, sourceRect, destRect, paint);  // this works fine

canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);   // the circle is drawn but not transparent
```

Comment: Try to call `setColor(0x77ff0000)` (or so) before `drawCycle`.

Answer (score 35):

I found it.

`paint.setAlpha` must come after `paint.setColor`

Comment: what a dump behaviour of this class >:(

Comment: maybe this is because setColor resets alpha to 255 (unless you specified an argb color with different alpha value), so setAlpha can hold only if it was called after...